# How do you back up all settings and themes (not the files)

Tags: gnome, backup, restore

I have installed the Gmac distro which is like macbuntu with gnome.  I have messed it up before and couldn't work out how to get it back to looking like a mac.  I just want to backup the appearance settings so if i mess up (was using tweak tool to add workspaces) I can just do a quick restore. I had only had it on for a couple of days so i just reinstalled to get back to original settings

Comment: Have you tried [aptik](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/aptik.html) ? It has what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/skel directory actually has all the settings of your systems. Backing up and restoring it to your new installation would help you.

Answer (score 0):

All of these configurations are stored in various hidden directories in your home directory.  Typically /etc/skel does not have these (although it may!), rather they are created on first run for each application with default values.  These files and directories are like the c:\users\username\appdata directory on windows, they hold all of the application specific preferences that aren't global to the system.

So... backup ~/.* and to restore delete any existing file/directory and put your backup copy back.  To revert to all default settings, either create a new user and log in as that user and copy the generated config files, or delete all of your .* and re-create.